# PHP Pthread start() method not working with Slim framework

Tags: php, pthreads, slim

```
namespace Service\Component\ThreadWebRequest;
use Thread;
class ThreadWebRequest extends Thread {

    public $url;
    public $headers;
    public $data;

    function __construct($url, $headers) {
      $this->url  = $url;
      $this->headers = $headers;
      //$this->start();
    }

    public function run() {
      $timeout = 0; // set to zero for no timeout
      $ch = curl_init();

      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0"); //Optional
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // Avoid SSL certificate issue
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
      $file_contents = curl_exec($ch);

      if(curl_errno($ch))
      {
          return 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
      }
      curl_close($ch);

      $this->data = $file_contents;
    }

}
```

In my controller I have this,

```
 $threadRequest = new ThreadWebRequest($value['uri'], $headers);
 $threadRequest->start() && $threadRequest->join();
 $batchResponse = $threadRequest->data;
```

I am getting this error.
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function findFile() on a non-object in /opt/services-api/v2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 300

If I access thread outside slim it's working fine. Not sure what needs be done to start a thread within slim framework router.

Comment: can you paste the code where is called findFile() function ?

Comment: `$threadRequest = new ThreadWebRequest($value['uri'], $headers);
                        $threadRequest->start(); 
                        $threadRequest->join();
                        $batchResponse = $threadRequest->data;` I am calling this inside my controller. I am getting php fatal error during call to my controller

Comment: Could you add namespace declaration in your controller please?

Comment: It is already there on top of the file. I have no fatal while create new object from `ThreadWebRequest` class.

Comment: That's class file, I meant the controller file, i.e. the one that contains this `new ThreadWebRequest` invocation. What type of autoloading you're using? PSR-4?

Comment: Yeah. Namespace is there in top controller file i.e `use Service\Component\ThreadWebRequest\ThreadWebRequest`.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: No. I can't solve with Slim.However I found alternative way do so.